# ListBox Bound to SortedSet. How To Bind TextBox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox, listbox

The ItemsSource (SsString) is a SortedSet string

I want to use a  TextBox (not the default TextBlock) in a ListBox but I cannot figure out how to bind to the value in the SortSet.

I have tried binding with no path, Key, key, Value, and value.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SsString}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The following works but it displays TextBlock.

```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SsString}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to edit the bound values. You need a class as the item so you can target a property with the `Binding.Path`.

(You should be able to bind this using `{Binding .}`, but it's one-way)

Comment: Thanks and plus 1 for knowing the answer to my second problem before I even knew I had it - how to bind two-way?

Comment: @Blam: For `TextBox.Text` binds `TwoWay` by default (see the [dependency property - metadata properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text.aspx)) if you have a path, if the property targeted has no setter it will throw an error.

Comment: I want the user to be able to edit string items in the list but I need to enforce uniqueness.  And if they enter a null to remove the item.   I am thinking I need to use an ObservableCollection and also pass the collection to the Item so the item can check for uniqueness

Comment: @Blam: That sounds rather messy, probably would be easier to validate the whole collection, rather than doing that on the item level.

Comment: OK then how?  At the item level I need to allow the update (and persists to SQL) or not.

Comment: @Blam: You could possibly save all values at once, but i don't know how you interact with your database; it's up to you in any case